# libtinfo6 is not installable

Tags: package-management

I am trying to install iraf and getting the error below. How to solve that, please?

https://github.com/iraf-community/x11iraf

```
sudo apt install gcc make bison flex libncurses-dev tcl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'libncurses-dev'
bison is already the newest version (2:3.0.4.dfsg-1build1).
flex is already the newest version (2.6.4-6).
make is already the newest version (4.1-9.1ubuntu1).
tcl-dev is already the newest version (8.6.0+9).
gcc is already the newest version (4:7.4.0-1ubuntu2.3).
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version (6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xgterm : Depends: libtinfo6 (>= 6) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify fy a solution).
```

I tried to write:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

It gives only some option.

I am using Linux Mint 19.2. When I wrote xgterm, I obtain

```
xgterm: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The `xgterm` package you’ve tried to install is too new for your system. Start by removing it:

```
apt purge xgterm
```

This will allow you to continue following the instructions for building iraf, which will include building a version of `xgterm` with appropriate dependencies for your system.